# Getting invalid syntax, and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, syntax

This is my code:

```
total = 0

s = "helloV"

for i in range(0, len(s)):
    total += 4 if s[i] == "V" else (total += 9) # The line where I'm getting the syntax error.
```

I'm not sure why this code is giving me a syntax error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be like this:

```
total = 0

s = "helloV"

for i in range(0, len(s)):
    total += 4 if s[i] == "V" else 9
```

When the if condition is true add `4` else add `9`.

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0

s = "helloV"

for i in range(0, len(s)):
    if s[i] == "V":
        total += 4
    else:
        total += 9
```

Above is a clear way to solve the syntax issues.

Answer (score -1):

You could also do something like this if you are looking for shorter code. It just uses a list comprehension that makes a list that has a `9` if the character in `s` does not equal `'V'`, and `4` if it does. Then, it just sums the resulting list with `sum()`:

```
s = "helloV"
total = sum([4 if i == 'V' else 9 for i in s])
```

Or you could use `map()` to just apply a `lambda` function to every element of `s` that does the same thing as explained above:

```
s = "helloV"
total = sum(map(lambda i: 4 if i == 'V' else 9, s))
```